# R: Way to map over all entries in a sparse matrix

Tags: r, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix created from R's Matrix package. I would like to iterate over each entry in the matrix and perform an operation, saving the result in another sparse matrix with the same indexes as the original matrix.

For example, let's say I have sparse matrix A:

```
1 . 1
2 . .
. . 4
```

ColSums would look like:

```
3 . 5
```

RowSums would look like:

```
2
2
4
```

I would like to iterate over A and do this

```
(1,1) > 3*2
(2,1) > 2*3
(1,3) > 2*5
(3,3) > 4*5
```

Creating B:

```
6 . 10
6 . .
. . 20
```

How would I go about doing this in a vectorized way?

I would think the function foo would look like:

```
B=fooMap(A,fun)
```

And fun would look like:

```
fun(row,col) = RowSums(row) * ColSums(col)
```

What's fooMap?

EDIT:

I went with flodel's solution. It uses summary to convert the sparse matrix into an i,j,x data frame, then uses with & friends to perform an operation on that frame, and then turns the result back into a sparse matrix. With this technique, the with/within operator is fooMap; the sparse matrix just has to be converted into the i,j,x data frame first so that with/within can be used.

Here's a one-liner that solved this particular problem.

```
B = with(summary(A), sparseMatrix(i=i, j=j, x = rowSums(A)[i] * colSums(A)[j]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I have element-wise operations on sparse matrices, I go back and forth between the matrix itself and its `summary` representation:

```
summ.B <- summary(A)
summ.B <- within(summ.B, x <- rowSums(A)[i]*colSums(A)[j])
B <- sparseMatrix(i = summ.B$i, j = summ.B$j, x = summ.B$x)
B
# 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#            
# [1,] 6 . 10
# [2,] 6 .  .
# [3,] . . 20
```

Comment: within looks extremely powerful. So within the within, you have read access to all of the columns in the object, referenced by their frame name? And that is used to build a slightly modified version of the original object, but as a new object that doesn't share any of the same memory, yes?

Comment: but if the matrix is huge, doesn’t this mean it takes up double space after that summary object is assigned to some variable?

Comment: Indeed. Temporarily doubling/tripling your memory usage is a very common task though, a necessary need to achieve speeds. If your data is so big that it uses more than half your memory, you are going to feel the pain...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that works with sparse matrices at each step.

```
## Load library and create example sparse matrix
library(Matrix)
m <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1,2,1,3), j = c(1,1,3,3), x = c(1,2,1,4))

## Multiply each cell by its respective row and column sums.
Diagonal(x = rowSums(m)) %*% (1*(m!=0)) %*% Diagonal(x = colSums(m))
# 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#            
# [1,] 6 . 10
# [2,] 6 .  .
# [3,] . . 20
```

(The `1*` in `(1*(m!=0))` is being used to coerce the logical matrix of class "lgCMatrix" produced by `m!=0` back to a numeric matrix class "dgCMatrix". A longer-winded (but perhaps clearer) alternative would to use `as(m!=0, "dgCMatrix")` in its place.)

Comment: This is very succinct. I may certainly use this for the case where the mapping function operator is *. And this is definitely a very common operation. But my linear algebra experience isn't too great. Does this approach generalize to other operators, say the rowSum + the colSum (instead of *)?

Comment: Sure you could do that, with something like this: `m2 <- 1*(m!=0); (Diagonal(x=rowSums(m)) %*% m2) + (m2 %*% Diagonal(x=colSums(m)))`. Until you get a reasonable feel for the basic matrix operations, though, making arbitrary generalizations may be a challenge.